# Generic parameter 'Parameters' could not be inferred

Tags: ios, swift

Unable to fetch data from API.

```
class GetData{

static let sharedInstance = GetData()

func callingGetAPI() {
    
let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
   
    AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default, headers: nil,interceptor: nil).response{
            responce in
        debugPrint(responce)
        switch responce.result{
        case .success(let data):
            do{
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data!)
                print(json)
            }catch{
                print( "Please Try again")
              //  completionHandler(.failure(.custom(message: "Please Try again")))
            }
        case .failure(let err):
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            print( "Please Try again")
        }



    }
}

}



struct Model:Codable {
let userId:Int
let id:Int
let title : String
let body: String
 }
```

Comment: Just write `AF.request(url, method: .get).response { ... }` But I'd suggest to use instead: `AF.request(url, method: .get).responseDecodable(of: Model.self) { result in ...`

Comment: `responseDecodable(of: [Model].self)`, forgot to add the "array" if you use that one.

Comment: Also, you can simply replace the encoder parameter in the request body with the encoding parameter and pass the value as JSONEncoding.default or JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted, 
And the encoder will accept the Encodable parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the above AF request with the below, which is using the parameter encoding instead of the encoder.

```
func callingGetAPI() {
    
    let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    
    AF.request(url,
               method: .get,
               encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted,
               headers: nil,
               interceptor: nil).response { response in
        debugPrint(response)
        
        switch response.result{
        case .success(let data):
            do{
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data!)
                print(json)
            }catch{
                print( "Please Try again")
                //  completionHandler(.failure(.custom(message: "Please Try again")))
            }
        case .failure(let err):
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            print( "Please Try again")
        }
    }
}
```